# Read txt files with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I've collected the GPS position data of my day into a txt file. There are N lines about my data. And there are 5 fields in one line(latitude, longitude, altitude, date, time). I want to use python read that. This is my code(There is no problem in this code).

```
 #open file
 f = open("path",'r')
 #read lines
 lines = f.read()
 print(lines)
 #close files
 f.close()
```

How can I read it like latitude, longitude or date, time? I just want one of the data in one line.

Comment: Try `lines.split(',')` after reading into `lines`. It would give a list. Index the list as per your needs.

Comment: Please include a sample from your text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the fields are split by commas you could do something like this

```
with open("path", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        latitude, longitude, altitude, date, time = line.split(",")
        do_something(latitude, longitude, altitude, date, time)
```